# How do you make $x$ the subject of $t=(x^2+1)^{1/2}+x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

**BACKGROUND**

I have been working through a book for STEP preparation and got stuck on part of an integration by substitution question (1998, Paper 1). For the substitution, I was struggling to rearrange for $x$ in terms of $t$. I thought that I might have used the wrong substitution but in the answers it does in fact make this rearrangement but skips the steps in between. I can't work out how it is done.

**PROBLEM**

Make $x$ the subject of $t=(x^2+1)^{1/2}+x$.

**ANSWER**

The answer given in the book is
$$x=\frac{(t^2-1)^{1/2}}{2t}$$

However, I have no idea how to get to this answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the trick here is to notice the following: you want to get rid of the square root. However, squaring both sides immediately does not accomplish this, because of the $+x$ term. That's why you should subtract $x$ from both sides, then square both sides, and then clean up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
t=(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}+x \\
t-x=(x^2+1)^\frac{1}{2} \\
t^2+x^2-2tx=x^2+1 \\
t^2-2tx=1 \\
2tx=t^2-1 \\
x=\frac{t^2-1}{2t}
$$

The solution provided is incorrect, and the correct solution is $\boxed{x=\dfrac{t^2-1}{2t}}$

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that $$\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)=1$$
We get
$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{x^2+1}+x=t \\
\Rightarrow \sqrt{x^2+1}-x=\frac{1}{t}
\end{aligned}
$$
Just subtract both the above equations, we get
$$2x=t-\frac{1}{t} \Rightarrow x=\frac{t^2-1}{2t}$$